# JavaFX cache not working at group level with high number of content elements

Tags: caching, javafx

I have a scene that contains a group whose content consists of a large number of polygons (1000x500).  I thought that by settings cache = true and/or cacheHint.SPEED at the group level that a single internal bitmap would be utilized for the numerous polygons.  However this appears not to be the case--frame rate stuck at a ~2fps.  Setting the cache on each polygon did not help either probably due to the large number of them.

Anyone know if setting cache at group level supposed to generate a single internal bitmap cache for the group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix was to enable cache for the group element but set the cache for individuals off.  I must have set to true for both.